# Game crashing when i run this function?

Tags: swift, audio

It's meant to be sound whenever the player collects a coin, but instead as soon as the character touches the coin the game freezes and exits.

```
 func playTap() {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tap", withExtension: "caf"){

        tap = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let tap = tap else { return }

        tap.prepareToPlay()
        tap.play()
} else {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the error message? And which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: I'm just curious.  Besides a crashing problem, why do you need to create an instance of an NSURL and AVPlayer when the user taps a coin?  Do you have only one coin during the entire game play?

Comment: Well Im doing a game like Flappy bird haha, Ive added coins in between every wall pair. So i want the sound to happen on every coin! @ElTomato

Comment: hi maddy, signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage and then at the bottom of the page it has a highlighted green line, thread 1 exc breakpoint.

By the way its some completely random page full of this stuff 
 0x10067d174 <+0>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #-80]!

@rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your code is crashing at since you are trying to **FORCE UNWRAP a null optional** with the **!** at the end of the line.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tap", withExtension: "caf")!
```

Try

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tap", withExtension: "caf"){
     //Code here
} else {
}
```

or

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tap", withExtension: "caf") else {}
```

**EDIT**

**Spell check key values!!**

Comment: @niX how did it go?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to reply! It didn't work in the end so I've given up for now I've been trying for so long >.< Does coding ever get any easier haha! Im constantly getting errors and everything feels like nothing ever works!

Comment: @niX maybe give it one more go and see if you spelled "tap" and "caf" right?? And I promise you'll get better with time!

Comment: The spellings definitely right! I edited the code original code I posted up the top ^^ Is that how it should look? @Mike JS Choi